# I can't write ANY text into the input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, p5.js

Question 1:
Hi, I am very new to p5.js and I am currently making a project programmed in it. I am meant to have an input box be displayed ONLY on the second screen (which is MENU=1), but for some reason I cannot write in the box at all, I can only write in it when I am on a different menu. Could anybody help please? Thank you.

[Input box doesn't accept any text input at all, like it's bugged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZaAh.png)

### Code below:

```js
let MENU = 0;
let img;
let gif_createImg;
var fade = 0;
var fadeSpeed = 1.0;

function preload() {
  StartImg = loadImage(imageUrl1);
  LoginImg = loadImage(imageUrl2);
  dnaGif = loadImage(imageUrl3);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1280, 720);
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 245)
  print(mouseX, mouseY)
  image(StartImg, 0, 0, width, height);
  image(dnaGif, 360, 200)

  function inputUsername() {
    let input1 = createInput()
    input1.position(474, 130);
    input1.size(500, 70)
  }


  if (MENU == 1) {
    background(255, 255, 245)
    fill(0)
    image(LoginImg, 0, 0, width, height);

    inputUsername()
    textSize(20)
    text('Right-Click to return to the start screen', 455, 693)
    if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
      MENU = 0
    }
  }

  if (MENU == 2) {
    background(255, 0, 0)
    textSize(20)
    text('Right-Click to return to the startscreen', 455, 693)
    if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
      MENU = 0
    }
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  if (MENU == 0) {
    if (mouseY < 582 && mouseY > 527) {
      if (mouseX < 527 && mouseX > 328) {
        MENU = 1
      }
      if (mouseX < 900 && mouseX > 706) {
        MENU = 2
      }
    }
  }
}

// These are data URLs for some solid color pngs to act as place holders for the images that would normally be used.
let imageUrlBase = "data:image/png;base64,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";
let imageUrl1 = imageUrlBase + "QOIkcg2PcAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAHUlEQVQ4y2NcoC7CQC5gYqAAjGoe1TyqeVQz5ZoBdtIBA8ORQl4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
let imageUrl2 = imageUrlBase + "QPBIw2bEsAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAHUlEQVQ4y2MUWSDGQC5gYqAAjGoe1TyqeVQz5ZoBJWIA8oj3qmoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
let imageUrl3 = imageUrlBase + "QPFeaGTLkAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAHUlEQVQ4y2MU0VzAQC5gYqAAjGoe1TyqeVQz5ZoBfz4BBQOizesAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Question 2:
If that can't be answered, can anybody explain why the input box is being output infinitely, I only want it to be output once. Thanks.

[Input box output indefinitely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OXUK.png)

### Code below:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function drawInput(){
  h = createInput()
  
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  drawInput()
}
```

Comment: Ask one question at one time . The reason for first question can be that text is entered but as it has image overlaying the text may be hidden behind the image

Comment: For some reason the input box only works if I am on a different menu, when I go to the menu it is meant to be shown on, on the text typed previously is removed.

Comment: The problem isn't the Image, I ran the after code removing all of the images and the problem still persists.

Comment: @Rana Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are creating the input over and over again inside the `draw()` function. All of the `create*()` functions in p5.js create a persistent HTML element. This is unlike the drawing methods like `rect()` and `ellipse()` which just draw something to the canvas that will be covered up or cleared when `background()` or `clear()` are called. You want to just create your inputs once when they are needed and then use `.remove()` to get rid of them when you are done.

```js
let MENU = 0;
let img;
let gif_createImg;
var fade = 0;
var fadeSpeed = 1.0;

function preload() {
  StartImg = loadImage(imageUrl1);
  LoginImg = loadImage(imageUrl2);
  dnaGif = loadImage(imageUrl3);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1280, 720);
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 245)
  image(StartImg, 0, 0, width, height);
  image(dnaGif, 360, 200)

  if (MENU == 1) {
    background(255, 255, 245)
    fill(0)
    image(LoginImg, 0, 0, width, height);

    textSize(20)
    text('Right-Click to return to the start screen', 455, 693)
    if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
      MENU = 0
    }
  }

  if (MENU == 2) {
    background(255, 0, 0)
    textSize(20)
    text('Right-Click to return to the startscreen', 455, 693)
    if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
      MENU = 0
    }
  }
}

function inputUsername() {
  let input1 = createInput();
  input1.position(474, 130);
  input1.size(500, 70);
  return input1;
}

let currentInput;
function mouseClicked(e) {
  // Simplified for testing
  // Ignore clicks inside of other HTML elements (like our <input>)
  if (e.target.nodeName === "CANVAS") {
    if (MENU === 0) {
      MENU = 1;
      currentInput = inputUsername();
    } else if (MENU === 1) {
      MENU = 2;
      currentInput.remove();
      currentInput = undefined;
    }
  }
}

// These are data URLs for some solid color pngs to act as place holders for the images that would normally be used.
let imageUrlBase = "data:image/png;base64,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";
let imageUrl1 = imageUrlBase + "QOIkcg2PcAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAHUlEQVQ4y2NcoC7CQC5gYqAAjGoe1TyqeVQz5ZoBdtIBA8ORQl4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
let imageUrl2 = imageUrlBase + "QPBIw2bEsAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAHUlEQVQ4y2MUWSDGQC5gYqAAjGoe1TyqeVQz5ZoBJWIA8oj3qmoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
let imageUrl3 = imageUrlBase + "QPFeaGTLkAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAAHUlEQVQ4y2MU0VzAQC5gYqAAjGoe1TyqeVQz5ZoBfz4BBQOizesAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, I looked at your answer and I understand how it works. I will just try change it from the simplified form so that the mouse boundaries work and so the right-click will take the user back to MENU 0 and delete the input box as required. Thanks for the help! @Paul Wheeler